# jquery form validation - error class to parent container

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I am using Jörn's jQuery validation - which you can view the full code for by [downloading it here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

I'm running into a bit of a problem, as I'm not entirely familiar with Javascript.

**Here's an example of my HTML**

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="myInput">My Input</label>
    <input id="myInput" name="myInput" type="text" />

    <span class="helptext">
        This is some help text for My Input...
    </span>
</div>
```

Essentially, the above HTML is repeated for each "section" of the form. `.helptext` is hidden via CSS, **unless the parent div has a class of `.error`**.

For example:
`<div class="field error">`

Here is what I believe to be the relevant code for the validation plugin - How would I make the error class be added to the parent `div.field`?

```
defaults: {
    messages: {},
    groups: {},
    rules: {},
    errorClass: "error",
    validClass: "valid",
    errorElement: "span.helptext",
    focusInvalid: true,
    errorContainer: $( ["div.field"] ),
    errorLabelContainer: $( [] ),
    onsubmit: true,
    ignore: [],
    ignoreTitle: false,
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the highlight/unhighlight handlers to add/remove classes, like this:

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {

    $(element).parent('.field').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);

},

unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {

    $(element).parent('.field').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);

}
```

Hope this helps, d.